# javascript try catch not fully working in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, try-catch

Can someone explain me why this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
        try {
            document.attribute-withminus = 5;
        }
        catch(e) {
            alert('something went wrong');
        }

        alert('ok');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Doesn't give me an alert with 'something went wrong' and also no alert with 'ok'?

It works fine in chrome. But in firefox, it just exits (it does show an error in the web console). The whole point of that try-catch is to make sure that if I type something wrong, it should give me an alert saying so. I don't want to have the web console open all the time.

Also, I know what is wrong here (minus sign in attribute; should use setAttribute). I'm asking why my error wasn't caught.

Comment: I experience this same problem.  I use try..catch to workaround a known problem with a certain JS library I'm using.  The workaround is perfect in IE and Chrome but not Firefox.  In Firefox is does not catch the exception and this means subsequent code below the error does not execute.  It is a problem.  And as for the comments here about syntax vs. early error -- they are all errors and I would expect try..catch to pick them up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.attribute-withminus = 5;
```

is a *syntax* error (probably something like *"invalid left hand part in assignement"*) which is an [*early* error](http://es5.github.io/#x16), not a *runtime* error.

The browser isn't supposed to execute the script containing it, it's supposed to stop and report the error as soon as it compiles the code containing the error, prior to any evaluation. In most browsers, the script would be wholly compiled before reaching the `try` clause. It works in Chrome because Chrome delays the compilation until it needs the internal block.

Comment: Yep, this is a longstanding bug in V8.  See https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1714

Comment: This isn't a matter of late compilation, or compilation at all.  V8 will throw early errors for other syntax issues; they just don't happen to check for this one.  Other browsers do similar simple syntax-only passes but _do_ check for this case as the spec requires.  And the spec is not vague at all; it clearly says that this case is an early error.