# Javascript use strict error not catching

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, error-handling, try-catch, use-strict

I am creating a backbone.js app that uses require.js for AMD. In order to check for `use strict` support in the browser, I have included the following code. However, when the code is run, the error thrown by `var o = {p:1, P:2}` is not caught as I expect it to be, and instead kills the entire page.

Chrome console prints this error: ***Uncaught SyntaxError: Duplicate data property in object literal not allowed in strict mode***

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'src/app'
], function(jQuery, _, Backbone, App){
    "use strict"

    var tooOld = true,
    isStrictMode = function () {
        try{
            var o = {p:1, p:2};
        } catch (e) {
            tooOld = false;
            new App;
        } finally {
            if (tooOld) {
                // Display some message
            }
        }
    }();
});
```

Why is the error crash my page instead of being caught? How can I fix this?

Comment: try to move "use strict" inside anonym function

Comment: Same result. The error continues to evade capture... "use strict" is working, because this error would not appear otherwise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript try catch not fully working in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037163/javascript-try-catch-not-fully-working-in-firefox)

Comment: Deliberately throwing an error is not a nice way to test things if there's an alternative, consider something like: `if (typeof (function(){return this;}()) == 'undefined') { /*in strict mode*/}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check for strict mode support, consider:

```
function supportsStrict() {
  'use strict';
  return typeof function(){return this;}() == 'undefined';
}

console.log(supportsStrict()); // true if supports strict mode
```

That way you can test independently and run different code branches depending on the result.

Comment: I ended up using something very similar: `var isStrictMode = function () { eval("var _temp = null"); if(typeof _temp === "undefined") { new App; } else { jQuery("#oldBrowser").toggle();}}();` Sorry about the poor format; comments don't let you do block code.

Comment: I guess that works, but why use *eval* when it's not required, and I don't see the point of the assignment, consider: `!function(){if(this)jQuery("#oldBrowser").toggle();else new App}()`. ;-)