# AngularJS - Use strict mode not working in resolve function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);
angular
  .module('app')
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      ...
      .when('/admin/users', { 
        templateUrl: '/partials/admin/users', 
        controller: 'usersController',
        resolve: { isAdmin: isAdmin }
      });
    })
isAdmin.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location'];
function isAdmin($rootScope, $location) {
  console.log("isAdmin");
  a = 12;
  console.log("isAdmin2");
}
}());
```

This code doesn't get to second console.log. There is no error in the console.

When I try sample code in the console (Firefox Quantum 58.0 (64 bits)), it works:

```
(function () {
  "use strict";
  c = 3;
})();
ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable c

(function () {
  u = 3;
})();
undefined
```

Strict mode works in controllers and services (browser console shows errors).

Comment: instantiate your variables with `var` (or `let`/`const` for ES6): `var a = 12;`

Comment: _if this (poorly asked) question is about **why** it doesn't throw an error_, consider [checking if `'user strict'` is supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25480113/8495123)